# Python dict contain dataframes , how to explode them in to separate rows

Tags: python, list, dataframe

```
R1 = {
    'mar': 'BS',
    'summary': pd.DataFrame({
        "year": [2002, 2003],
        "customers": [400, 230],
        "count": [180, 115]}),
    'params': {
        'r': 1,
        'o': 4
    }
}

R2 = {
    'mar': 'NY',
    'summary': pd.DataFrame({
        "year": [2002, 2003],
        "customers": [410, 220],
        "count": np.array([180, 115])}),
    'params': {
        'r': 2,
        'o': 5
    }
```

Convert this to below format

```
   mar      r   o   year    customers   count
0  NY       0.00    0.0     2002    58      400   
1  NY       0.00    0.0     2003    220         230             
2  BS       0.02    0.0     2002    180         410             
3  BS       0.02    0.0     2003    115         220
```

I think these sufficient details, please help me to write this function, I am new to handling this

Comment: The dictionary you give isn't a valid dictionary. Did you mean for `d["summary_yearly"]` to be a dataframe?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I have added more details Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the additional information: Try

```
results = [RESULT_1, RESULT_2]

df = pd.concat(
    (
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                'market': result['market'],
                **result['model_params'],
                **result['summary_yearly'].to_dict(orient='list')
            }
        )
        for result in results
    ),
    ignore_index=True
)
```

or, probably better,

```
results = [RESULT_1, RESULT_2]

f = pd.concat(
    (
        result['summary_yearly'].assign(
            **{'market': result['market'], **result['model_params']}
        )
        for result in results
    ),
    ignore_index=True
)
df = df[df.columns.to_list()[-3:] + df.columns.to_list()[:-3]]
```

Results:

```
     market  rete_increase  ...  weekly_active_customers  box_count
0    Boston            0.0  ...                      400      180.0
1    Boston            0.0  ...                      230     1150.0
2  New York            0.0  ...                      410      183.6
3  New York            0.0  ...                      220      117.3

[4 rows x 7 columns]
```

I guess you'd replace `results` with `sensi.results` after adding the results to `sensi`.

---

Additional question from the comments:

```
cols = ["conversions", "weekly_active_customers", "box_count"]
df[[f"{c} 2023 vs 2022" for c in cols]] = df.groupby("market")[cols].pct_change()
```

Comment: I have added more details, I will try what you suggested

Comment: @makhai I've adujusted the answer to incorporate the new information.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you help me to include 3 additional columns for:
        - conversions 2023 vs 2022 yoy growth
        - weekly_active_customers 2023 vs 2022 yoy growth
        - box_count 2023 vs 2022 yoy growth

Comment: @makhai See edit. Generally follow up questions are usually frowned upon here. If this answer solved your original question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you have other questions please consider asking them in a new thread instead of adding 'follow up' questions here. Not only are such follow up questions frustrating for the answer giver, they also make it impossible to others with the same problem solve their issue.

Comment: I am sorry for that, this is the first time i am using this to ask a question. Will do as you suggested. Thank you for the help

Comment: @makhai No problem!

Comment: If you can please check this question also, related to this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70020688/slicing-of-list-contain-datafram-and-strings)