# Slicing of List contain datafram and strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, slice

```
R_1 = {
    'market': 'Boston',
    'summary': pd.DataFrame({
        "year": [2022, 2023],
        "customers": [400, 230],
        "count": [180, 1150]}),
    }
}

R_2 = {
    'market': 'New York',
    'summary': pd.DataFrame({
        "year": [2022, 2023],
        "customers": [410, 220],
        "count": np.array([185, 115])}),

    }
}
```

then I used a function to append these results

```
    def get_results_max(self, market: str, metric: str, year: int) -> dict

        """
    I need help to write this function
        """
```

then call below to append all, there are many result files

```
get_max(market= 'New York', metric= "count", year: 2022)
```

I need dict with the max box_count value for New York in 2022 with other values also

Comment: in the function, loop over all items of your result dict, check if the market is the same, and then  find the max value. Not sure what the box_count is for though

Comment: box_count is under summary_yearly in the results, how to slice it using year, that we check if it is eqal, then we need the max value for box_count

Comment: Oh, so you want to find max value from that array? Okay, what seems to be the issue?

Comment: from all the results, i need the max value for box_count variable in year 2022 and in new york, NOTE: I have more RESULT files with more data for new York, i just added 2

Comment: Yes, but what's the issue? Loop through all results, check if the result has your desired data (year, market) and keep the highest value stored.

Comment: I dont know how to write the code to slice it that way, can you provide me a example code

Comment: Slice what exactly?

Comment: you can't `slice` it - you have to use `for`-loop to check every element separatelly

Comment: Wehen execute sensi.get_results_max(market= 'New York', metric= "box_count", year: 2022), i want to get the box_count. I dont know how to explain it any other way.

Comment: what did you try to do this? Yo keep results on list - so first you have to use `for`-loop to work with every dictionary separatelly. And next you can use keys in dictionary to check `market` and next get use `year`, `metric` to get data from DataFrame. You can't do it using simple `slice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
    ...

    def get_results_max(self, market, metric, year):
        metrics = [
            result["summary_yearly"].loc[
                result["summary_yearly"].year.eq(year), metric
            ].max()
            for result in self.results if result["market"] == market
        ]
        if metrics:
            return max(metrics)
        print(f"No result for market '{market}', metric '{metric}' and year '{year}'")
```

Result for

```
sensi = Sensi()
sensi.add_result(RESULT_1)
sensi.add_result(RESULT_2)
print(sensi.get_results_max(market= 'New York', metric= "box_count", year=2022))
```

is

```
A new result for Boston has been added.
A new result for New York has been added.
188.70000000000002
```